# Two variadic templates for a single function?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, variadic-templates, variadic-functions

In C++11 is it possible to have two variadic templates for a single function ?

If not, is there a trick to write something like that :

```
template <class... Types, class... Args> 
void f(const std::tuple<Types...>& t, Args&&... args)
```

Comment: You mean `template<typename... A1, typename... A2> void f(A1&&... a1, A2&&... a2)`?

Comment: I'm wondering if I haven't misunderstood the question

Comment: @Yakk : I think that the one you write is not legal (the compiler has no mean to "cut" somewhere between A1 and A2).

Comment: @AndyProwl : If your example compiles, then you have answered my question

Comment: @Vincent: [It does for me](http://liveworkspace.org/code/20xXyn$1)

Comment: @Yakk that's legal. Calling `f(1, 2)` deduces `A1` as empty and `A2` as `{int, int}`.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb What would be the result if we want to explicitely specify a type conversion: f<double, double>(1, 2) ? (is A1 empty and A2 = {double, double})

Comment: @Vincent the first template parameter pack slurps all arguments. So the result is that `A1` is `{double, double}` and `A2` is empty.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

That's perfectly legal:

```
#include <tuple>

using namespace std;

template <class... Types, class... Args>
void f(const std::tuple<Types...>& t, Args&&... args)
{
    // Whatever...
}

int main()
{
    std::tuple<int, double, bool> t(42, 3.14, false);
    f(t, "hello", true, 42, 1.0);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know that was legal and I thought it needed a kind of metaprogramming hack.