# Two variadic templates for a single function? Part 2

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, variadic-templates

As continuation for: [Two variadic templates for a single function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15043527/two-variadic-templates-for-a-single-function)

I need a function with two variadic type lists.

Example:

```
template<typename... Types, typename... Args>
void function(Args&&... args) {
   ...
}

// usage
function</* types list for Types variadic */>(1,2,3/* arguments for Args */)
```

Thanks.

Comment: Uh... what's the problem? Just use it like that.

Comment: Hmm... I thought that it would be wrong...

Comment: Always try to compile your code before blindly asking a question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That should just work:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <tuple>

template<typename... Types, typename... Args>
void fxn(Args&&... args) {
   static_assert(
       std::is_same<std::tuple<Types...>, std::tuple<int, bool>>::value, "!");
   static_assert(
       std::is_same<std::tuple<Args...>, std::tuple<int, double, char>>::value, "!");
}

int main()
{
    fxn<int, bool>(42, 3.14, 'c');
}
```

[**Live example**](http://ideone.com/kaIJSs).