# C++ variadic template return type

Tags: c++, variadic-templates, return-type

My function calls a Python function with a set of given input arguments (variadic) and returns a tuple containing the function's output (variadic because output varies on the function called).

I'm compiling on a Windows 10 machine via MinGW-w64 compiler's port of g++ using C++11. I've declared this templated variadic function (and call it) as follows:

```
// Declaration (in PyInterface.h)
template <typename... Inputs, typename... Outputs>
const std::tuple<Outputs...>& callFunction(const std::string &modulePath, const std::string &funcName, Inputs&&... args) { 
    // Calls a Python function & packs output variables into a std::tuple... 
}

// Sample call (in main.cpp)
const std::tuple<std::string, std::string> output = pi.callFunction(myModulePath, myFuncName, inputArg1, inputArg2, inputArg3);
```

However, this error is thrown (shortened with `...` for readability):

`conversion from 'const std::tuple<>' to non-scalar type 'const std::tuple<std::__cxx11::basic_string<...>, std::__cxx11::basic_string<...> >' requested`

As far as I'm aware [using two variadic templates is legal](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15043549/5209610). Additionally, it seems to me that the return type is explicitly set by the variable (`const std::tuple<std::string, std::string> output`) I am attempting to assign the result of the function to, so the compiler should know what the desired return 
type is.

Originally, I thought that the error simply indicated that I wasn't using the variadic templates appropriately. I tried using nested template parameters (illustrated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12782697/5209610)) to specify the return type (i.e., `const T<Outputs...>& callFunction`). However, this only succeeded in producing an error message indicating that template deduction of `T` had failed.

This error indicates that my intuition is wrong and that, in my original function, the compiler isn't deducing the desired return type from `output`'s type.

Why is my intuition wrong? How do I correctly use a variadic template to specify this function's return type?

Comment: You never specify the types for `Outputs` so there are none.

Comment: @NathanOliver Could you elaborate as to how I specify the types for `Outputs`? I already tried to modify my call to `pi.callFunction<std::string>`, but I couldn't figure out what the error message meant: `error: cannot bind 'const string {aka const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>}' lvalue to 'std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>&&'`

Comment: You are explicitly specifying `string` as an Input type. You get an rvalue reference with that is combined with the function argument declaration `Inputs &&`. You are passing an lvalue of `const string` which would at least require removal of the `const` before it could be used. Besides the answer I gave where the Input types are picked up implicitly, you could explicitly specify `const string &` as an Input type, which remains a `const string &` when combined with `Inputs &&`.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to deduce the return type based on the type of an object being returned that is in the scope of the function, if you are on C++14 then you can just use `auto` as the return type.  It works like a charm

```
template <typename... Inputs>
const auto& callFunction(
    const std::string &modulePath, 
    const std::string &funcName, 
    Inputs&&... args) { 

    return object;
}
```

As always beware that you are returning a const reference from this function.

If you are using C++11 then you can use trailing return types, for example

```
template <typename T>
auto identity_return(T& obj) -> decltype(obj) {
    return obj;
}
```

where `decltype(obj)` is the type of the thing you want to return.  Again beware in this case it is again a reference.

In general though try and return values from a function, returning references can lead to dangling references if you are not sure what you are returning will outlive the return.

---

Another solution is to just specify the `Outputs...` type list manually and let the compiler deduce the types `Inputs...`

```
template <typename... Outputs, typename... Inputs>
const std::tuple<Outputs...>& callFunction(
    const std::string &modulePath, 
    const std::string &funcName, 
    Inputs&&... args) { ... }

auto tup = callFunction<std::string, std::string>(modulePath, funcName, args);
```

Comment: You're returning a reference to a local object which is destroyed.

Comment: @NathanOliver That is why I mentioned the "beware" thing in the end!

Comment: I guess what I am trying to communicate is why use bad code in your example when you can do it "the right way" and explain to the OP why you did so.

Comment: @NathanOliver sure, I get what you mean.  I just thought that OP might have had something more complicated going on under the hood which required returning a reference (like a singleton) so I didn't speculate, but you are right.  I will make an edit

Comment: @VladislavMartin updated my answer to address C++11 auto return types as well

Comment: @Curious I don't understand how this solution will work. In my case, `obj` isn't contained in the input arguments & it is a tuple with a parameter pack: `-> decltype(std::tuple<obj...>)`. How can I extend this solution to fit my code?

Comment: @VladislavMartin in your code, where do you get the type list `obj...` from?

Comment: @VladislavMartin just trying to understand, how do you declare the variable `output` in your code?

Comment: @VladislavMartin but what is the line in the function that does the actual `return`?  And what variable does that line return?  And how is that variable declared in the body of the function?

Comment: @VladislavMartin you cannot declare a variable of type `std::tuple<>` and then grow it by calling `tuple_cat`  that will not compile.  You are going to have to think of how to get the list of types that you make with `tuple_cat` differently

Comment: @VladislavMartin What is the type of the dummy variable you use to populate the tuple?  Also is the number of times the loop runs set at compile time?  I feel like you need to provide more information about how the code looks *inside* `callFunction`, I'm just guessing right now

Comment: @VladislavMartin because in the function you are creating a type list with some logic only the code inside the function can reveal.  And I am only guessing how you are going about creating such a type list.  Because right now you are saying you are using loops, which are usually a runtime construct, and I am unable to understand how you are constructing a type list from a loop

Comment: @VladislavMartin Maybe the simplest thing you could do is just explicitly specify the `Outputs...` type list manually when calling the function?

Comment: @VladislavMartin I don't think I can answer the question with the amount of information I have currently, sorry.  I just dont understand how you decide how many times to call the python function and what you are doing in your loop

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147978/discussion-between-vladislav-martin-and-curious).

Comment: @VladislavMartin unfortunately I have time restrictions right now so wont be of much help anymore. Sorry! But I strongly think you can find out how to construct your tuple without that loop if you look into the implementations of things like std::apply and related questions like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/687490/how-do-i-expand-a-tuple-into-variadic-template-functions-arguments. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

As usual with C++ compiler error messages, the first one is the only one you need to look at. I'm guessing (because you didn't provide the code) that you are creating a `tuple` value and then returning a const reference to it. At the end of the function, the `tuple` is destroyed so what should the reference refer to? You should just return `tuple<Outputs...>`.

I think you can achieve what you want by swapping the `Input` and `Output` type packs. This code also illustrates iterating over the `Inputs` type pack with the `show` function. You can do a similar thing to build a `tuple<Outputs...>` value from a Python tuple object and the `Outputs` type pack.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>
#include <utility>

using namespace std;

template< typename Output > struct convert_t;
template<> struct convert_t< string >
{
    string operator()( const char *text ) const
    {
        return text;
    }

    string operator()( double val ) const
    {
        return to_string( val );
    }
};

inline void show()
{}

template< typename First, typename... Others >
inline void show( First &&first, Others&&... others )
{
    cout << first << "\n";
    show( forward< Others >( others )... );
}

template< typename... Outputs, typename... Inputs >
inline tuple< Outputs... > funkyfunc( Inputs&&... inputs )
{
    cout << "Inputs...\n";
    show( forward< Inputs >( inputs )... );
    return tuple< Outputs... >( convert_t< Outputs >()( inputs )... );
}

int main()
{
    auto t = funkyfunc< string, string >( "text", 123.0 );
    cout << "Outputs...\n";
    cout << get<0>( t ) << "\n";
    cout << get<1>( t ) << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```